# relatedTo doesn't seem to work when using multiple sections in a craft.entries call

Tags: entries, relatedto

I can do `craft.entries.section('mySection').relatedTo(item.id)` and it will return the result, so i assumed i could do `craft.entries.section(['mySection','mySection2','mySection3']).relatedTo(item.id)` but, the latter seems to return no results.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the 3 sections have elements related to your `item.id`?  If you take off the `relatedTo` part, do you get all entries across all 3 sections?

Comment: Ah, now, does it mean it will return entries where they have a relationship in `mySection AND mySection2 AND mySection3` rather than the desired `mySection OR mySection2 OR mySection3` ?

Comment: Without looking at the code... about 90% sure it will end up being an OR.

Comment: Well, the 3 sections do have elements related to item.id and if i take off the relatedTo part, i do indeed get entries across all 3 sections! No idea why it's not returning entries in my original code!

Comment: maybe change relatedTo(item.id) to relatedTo(item)

Comment: Yep, was one step ahead of you, i had already tried that! No dice however.

Comment: Sorry - more questions. Is `item` defined? Is it an `entry` object and does the query return anything with only one section?